# Printing an upside down triangle made of asterisks

Tags: java

```
class upsidedown {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x, y;
        for (y = 1; y <= 5; y++) {
            for (x = 0; x < 5 - y; x++) {
                System.out.print(' ');
            }
            for (x = (2 - y); x < (2 - y) + (2 * y - 1); x++) {
                System.out.print('*');
            }
            System.out.print('\n');
        }
    }
}
```

So far my code prints out a regular, right side up triangle. How do I make it upside down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easily. Using your same logic, just reverse the order that you print your lines with.

```
public class UpsideDown {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x, y;
        for (y = 5; y >= 1; y--) { //reverse here
            for (x = 0; x < 5 - y; x++)
                System.out.print(' ');
            for (x = (2 - y); x < (2 - y) + (2 * y - 1); x++)
                System.out.print('*');
            System.out.print('\n');
        }
   }
}
```

Also, please follow [java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html).

Comment: why do I need to follow java naming conventions?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-139411.html#16712