# Recursive Triangle

Tags: java, recursion

So, I've been assigned a problem where I have to have a user-inputted number (an int) generate a triangle of the given size. i.e. if the user types in "5" as the size, the program would generate the following:

Where the peak of the triangle, or the largest row, would be the desired size.
Here's the catch - we have to use a second method to do this, and that method can only accept two arguments. That method also has to be the only one used to make the triangle. To clarify- we can't separate the triangles into two halves, one for the first half, (increasing asterisks) and one for the second. We also can't use loops. (decreasing) My program, so far, has 3 methods (including main) a method like asked, used to identify what's being printed, ans a method to actually print the rows. However, I can't quite seem to get it right. Any help as to how?

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of `for` loops `System.out.print` and `System.out.println` statements. You could also try Google. Millions of people have made this tiny exercise.

- [Creating a triangle with for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409621/creating-a-triangle-with-for-loops)
- [java asterisk right triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542113/java-asterisk-right-triangle)
- [Printing an upside down triangle made of asterisks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485710/printing-an-upside-down-triangle-made-of-asterisks)
- http://javaandj2eetutor.blogspot.be/2013/07/java-code-to-print-astrisc-pyramid.html

Etc... So lots of demo's to learn from.

Answer (score 0):

~~Writing from my phone so I'm sorry~~ edit: now im on my pc, i will describe it a little better

```
void pyramid(int height){ // wrapper method
    foo(1, height);
}

void foo(int a, int b){
    if(a == b)
        if( a== 0) return;
        else b = 0;
    for(int = 0; i < a; ++i)
        System.out.print("*");
    System.out.println();
    if(a < b) foo(a+1, b);
    else foo(a-1, b);
}
```

method foo:
a is the current height, and b is the maximum height of our pyramid.
if a and b are the same (which is the first time, when we reach the peak) we set b to 0, which is an indicator for us to decrease the height.
the second time a and b are equal is, when both are 0, which means our pyramid is finished, and we can end (return;)

to "build" the pyramid, we use a loop to print `a`-many asterisks in the same row

see `print()` instead of `println()`

after that i use `println()` for the line break.

now simple check if " a < b " which means we need to increase the height, if its false we need to decrease the height

a == b will never occur because we catched that case at the beginning

then call depending on increasing or decreasing the foo method recursively

**note:** i made the code yesterday evening from my phone and i haven't tested it so far, but with my description you may get the idea behind it and you are able to fix errors yourself (if there are any)

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void printTriangle(int size) {
    int peak = 0;
    StringBuilder triangle = new StringBuilder();
    do {
        if (size % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Size of triangle must be an odd number: 1, 3, 5, ...");
            break;
        }
        if (peak <= size / 2) {
            System.out.println(triangle.append("*"));
            peak++;
        }

        if (peak > size / 2) {
            System.out.println(triangle.deleteCharAt(0));
            peak++;
        }

    } while (peak < size);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain how does it work.